# Flexible button width according another buttons width

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I try to make 3 buttons with vertical orientation, the problem is the first button have the widest than others, How I can make two others button automatic follow the first button width?

[image]
Should like this >
[image]

**Below is the example of my code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="THIS IS JUST A EXAMPLE BUTTON"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUTTON 2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUTTON 3"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your LinearLayout Like this, it will work fine

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="THIS IS JUST A EXAMPLE BUTTON" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUTTON 2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUTTON 3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do if you'll be willing to use `ConstraintLayout`. You just need to tweak some parts but it'll look like how your example looks if you don't really need it look like a table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="THIS IS JUST A EXAMPLE BUTTON"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:text="BUTTON 2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:text="BUTTON 3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```